# give users the option to sort a list created from a txt document based on input

Tags: python, list

This program will ask the user the class they want to view the results for and ask them how they want to sort them. the list is created from the lines in a text document.
All that the program needs to do now is after the sort selection has been made to sort and then print in the way chosen.

```
print ("Please enter the class number below.")
print ("After that please select how you would like to sort them")

classnumber = input("Which results do you want to view? (enter class number)")

if classnumber == ('1'):
        li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("class1.txt").readlines()]
if classnumber == ('2'):
        li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("class1.txt").readlines()]
if classnumber == ('3'):
        li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("class1.txt").readlines()]

print ("Press a For Alphabetically")
print ("Press h For Highest To Lowest")
print ("Press m For Mean (Average Highest To Lowest)")

sort = input ("How would you like to sort the results?")

if sort == 'a':
        sorted("class1.txt")
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class1.txt").readlines()])
if sort == 'h':
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class.2txt").readlines()])
if sort == 'm':
        averages=[]
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class3.txt").readlines()])
```

How would I get the if statements to sort how the user selects and then print the list in the right order?

Comment: You have many typographical errors there...

Comment: the program ends and doesn't print the sorted list.

Comment: You should break down your codes for smaller parts of it, and go through each part to check it behaves as expected. If not, please post a more specific question. This one is just too broad.

Comment: this part sorts correctly but can't find the txt document it's sorting and it doesn't print                                                                                                                         if sort == 'a':
        sorted("class1.txt")
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class1.txt").readlines()])
if sort == 'h':
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class.2txt").readlines()])
if sort == 'm':
        averages=[]
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class3.txt").readlines()])

Comment: What does the initial text document look like?

Comment: Could you please give us some example data showing what the class files look like?

Comment: Class files have the person's name followed by a space, eg: Test, 4 (test = name, 4=score)

Answer (score 1):

In this section of your code, you open the files, and read through all the lines, saving the output in a list called `li`:

```
if classnumber == ('1'):
        li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("class1.txt").readlines()]
if classnumber == ('2'):
        li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("class1.txt").readlines()]
if classnumber == ('3'):
        li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("class1.txt").readlines()]
```

Then in this section of your code, you try to read through the lines in the file object again, but 1) you never actually open the file, and 2) if you use the same file object, it will output an empty string because you've already read over all the lines in the file and the cursor is at the end.

```
if sort == 'a':
        sorted("class1.txt")
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class1.txt").readlines()])
if sort == 'h':
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class.2txt").readlines()])
if sort == 'm':
        averages=[]
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in ("class3.txt").readlines()])
```

Because you've already read everything into this list named `li`, you can use that instead of trying to open the file again, like this:

```
if sort == 'a':
        sorted("class1.txt")
        print([i.strip().split() for i in li])
if sort == 'h':
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in li])
if sort == 'm':
        averages=[]
        sorted(reverse=True)
        print([i.strip().split() for i in li])
```

You still have some errors regarding the use of the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function, namely that `sorted()` returns a copy of the list sorted, it does not modify the original list.

It's also worth mentioning that you never actually `close()` your file objects which is a disaster waiting to happen. I would use the `with` keyword as a context manager to ensure the files are properly closed.